# How can I tell Perl to run some code every 20 seconds?

Tags: perl

How can I tell Perl to run some code every 20 seconds?

Comment: To the people down-voting this question, stop and think about it for a few minutes.  A simple answer like `sleep 20;` is only a partial solution.

Comment: @Chas. - The problem is that the question didn't explicitly specify that (see Ether/Blrfl comments on the answer). Thus, the question IS bad, even if what's being asked is not.

Comment: @DVK Yes, there are all sorts of complications that come up (should the code execute every twenty seconds with overlaps, without overlaps, on twenty second boundaries, on the 0th, 20th, and 40th second of a minute, etc.).  These are all refinements to the question that are needed, but down-votes won't get the refinements, especially without someone commenting on why it is not a very good question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while (1) {
        sleep 20;
        <your code here>;
}
```

Comment: That depends.  Does the code have to start on 20-second boundaries, or should there be 20 seconds between the last iteration finishing and the start of the next one?

Answer (score 22):

```
for (;;) {
    my $start = time;
    # your code;
    if ((my $remaining = 20 - (time - $start)) > 0) {
        sleep $remaining;
    }
}
```

Comment: @daxim It does suffer from drift if the `#your code` part takes longer than twenty seconds.  To prevent drift it would need to be `sleep(($interval - (time - $start)) % $interval)` where `$interval` is twenty.

Comment: @daxim Of course, that suffers from a possible drift of just shy of a second per twenty.

Answer (score 9):

While the `sleep` function will work for some uses, if you're trying to do "every 20 seconds, forever", then you're better off using an external utility like `cron`.

In addition to the possible issue of drift already mentioned, if your `sleep` script exits (expectedly or otherwise), then it's not going to run again at the next 20 second mark.

@Blrfl is correct, and I feel sheepish.  That said, it's easy enough to overcome.

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.pl
* * * * * sleep 20 && /path/to/script.pl
* * * * * sleep 40 && /path/to/script.pl
```

You could also take a hybrid approach of putting a limited count sleep loop in the script and using cron to run it every X minutes, covering the case of script death.  Anything more frequent than 20 seconds, I would definitely take that approach.

Comment: POSIX `cron` doesn't do sub-minute resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I need a command to be executed exactly every second (as a workaround for the crappy energy metering interface of my Shelly 3EM), so I ended up with this approach, using one line per second (well, not nice, but very reliable and pretty precise).

Answer (score 9):

Set up a SIGALRM handler, and send yourself a signal every 20 seconds with `alarm` (see [perldoc -f alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)):

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    # set up the next signal for 20 seconds from now
    alarm 20;

    # do whatever needs to be done
    # ...
};
```

This will experience drift over time, as each signal may be delayed by up to a second; if this is important, set up a cron job instead.  Additionally, even more drift will happen if your other code takes upwards of 20 seconds to run, as only one timer can be counting at once.  You could get around this by spawning off threads, but at this point, I would have already gone back to a simple cron solution.

Choosing the proper solution is dependent on what sort of task you need to execute periodically, which you did not specify.

Answer (score 3):

See [Schedule::ByClock](https://metacpan.org/pod/Schedule::ByClock):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Schedule::ByClock;

my $scheduler = Schedule::ByClock->new(0, 20, 40);

while ( defined( my $r = $scheduler->get_control_on_second ) ) {
    printf "%02d\n", $r;
}
```

All the caveats others pointed out still apply, but I think the module is neat.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;


# heartbeat
$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    # set up the next signal for 20 second from now
    alarm(20);
    printf "<heartbeat/>\n";
};

alarm(20); # start timer
my $i = 0;
while(1) {
    $i++;
    printf "loop" . $i . "\n";
    sleep 2;
}

alarm(0);

printf "done!\n";
```

Output :

```
loop1
loop2
loop3
loop4
loop5
loop6
loop7
loop8
loop9
loop10
<heartbeat/>
loop11
loop12
loop13
loop14
loop15
loop16
loop17
loop18
loop19
loop20
<heartbeat/>
```

Comment: Probably some annotation will be welcomed. Best regards

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use some event library. There are a couple of choices:

[IO::Async::Timer::Periodic](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Timer::Periodic)

```
use IO::Async::Timer::Periodic;

use IO::Async::Loop;
my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;

my $timer = IO::Async::Timer::Periodic->new(
   interval => 60,

   on_tick => sub {
      print "You've had a minute\n";
   },
);

$timer->start;

$loop->add( $timer );

$loop->run;
```

[AnyEvent::DateTime::Cron](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::DateTime::Cron)

```
AnyEvent::DateTime::Cron->new()
    ->add(
        '* * * * *'   => sub { warn "Every minute"},
        '*/2 * * * *' => sub { warn "Every second minute"},
      )
    ->start
    ->recv
```

[EV::timer](https://metacpan.org/pod/EV#TIMER-WATCHERS-relative-and-optionally-repeating-timeouts)

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Go with ..

```
while () {
  sleep 20;
  #Code here
}
```